# Yahoo API callout failing

Tags: apex, callout, calloutexception

Below code was working fine few days back. Suddenly stopped working and throws error.

```
String endPoint = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=';
String queryUrl = 'select item.condition from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text=Bangalore) and u=c';
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
Http httpProtocol  = new Http();
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setEndpoint(endPoint + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(queryUrl, 'UTF-8'));
HttpResponse res = httpProtocol.send(req);
System.debug(res);
```

Getting callout exception:

> System.CalloutException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns
>   "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"

When I tried this in Chrome REST Client getting different error:

> The requested URL can't be reached
>
> The service's server DNS address could not be found.
>
> Search Google for chrome network error 105
>
> net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: Hi reshma, I am not able to reach  from my browser `https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q` . Am sure SF wont be able to reach as well

Comment: Is this issue related to yahoo's api server? It was working few days back.

Comment: Yes.. Even this link from their doc is not working. I believe its yahoo's issue. https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql_code_tutorials.html?guccounter=1

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue right now and just found out Yahoo retired the API.

> On Jan. 3, 2019, YQL service at http://query.yahooapis.com  will be retired. YQL based services that use http://query.yahooapis.com , including users of http://datatables.org , will no longer operate. Yahoo Weather API users see the tweet below for info about continuing your service.

From: https://twitter.com/ydn/status/1079785891558653952

Comment: Thanks Frank for the update. Posted the updated api documentation as answer. Please refer if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have got documentation on updated yahoo api to use instead of the retired one. Official announcement says:

> As of Thursday, Jan. 3, 2019, the YQL service at query.yahooapis.com
>   will be retired. This will impact users of datatables.org as well as
>   developers who creates features using this YQL service.  To continue
>   using our free Yahoo Weather APIs, use
>   https://weather-ydn-yql.media.yahoo.com/forecastrss. Follow
>   instructions [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/) to get credentials and onboard to this free Yahoo
>   Weather API service

For doing callout to the updated API requires to do oAuth and get API keys. Here is the detailed documentation on [Yahoo Weather API for your apps](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/), [Yahoo Query Language (YQL)](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) and [Yahoo Weather API Documentation](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/documentation.html)